# Give an output when a string is a certain word?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n;
    cout << "Enter the name of an automobile: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while( n != "End") {
        if( n == ("Tesla" or "Volt" or "Leaf")) {
            cout << "Electric" << endl;}
            else {
                if( n == ("Clarity" or "Mirai")){
                    cout << "Hydrogen Powered" << endl;}

                else {
                    cout << "Gas Powered" << endl; }}
        cout << "Enter the name of an automobile: " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

It needs to say how each automobile is powered. Basically if I input "Tesla", it should say "Electric"; "Ford" should come up "Gas Powered". It ends when I enter "End". 
I get this error 
.cpp|16|error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') and 'bool')|

Comment: I know it's real easy, I am still struggling to figure out syntax. Just started this semester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if( n == ("Tesla" or "Volt" or "Leaf"))
```

needs to be changed to

```
 if( (n == "Tesla") || (n == "Volt") || (n == "Leaf") )
```

Make similar changes at the other places where you do the same thing

- There is no `or` keyword in C++. You need to use `||`
- ("Tesla || "Volt" || "Leaf") would always return true. So the condition will become if (n == (true)) which will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

This should work! In C++ there is no `or`. Use `||`. Also the condition needs to be put each time in `if` like `if(n=="Tesla"||n=="Volt"||n=="Leaf")`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n;
    cout << "Enter the name of an automobile: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while( n != "End") {
        if( n == "Tesla" || n== "Volt" ||n== "Leaf") {
            cout << "Electric" << endl;}
            else {
                if( n == "Clarity" || n=="Mirai"){
                    cout << "Hydrogen Powered" << endl;}

                else {
                    cout << "Gas Powered" << endl; }}
        cout << "Enter the name of an automobile: " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }

    return 0;

}
```